# How to "group" a list of elements based on a certain criteria, but at the same time keep it as a list? .NET Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

We're working on the back end of a web application. The user can review all of their previous orders via a route that returns them as a list from a database. Each order contains information such as amount, status (pending/successful/failed), type of item etc. The user can filter/sort through the list.

Now, my team is tasked to make it possible for the user to group their list of orders based on a certain criteria, let's say the status. The user will also be displayed the total amount of each "group". So for example, the list will be ordered so that the "successful" transactions come first, then the pending ones, then the failed ones.

Now. Our code in the OrderService returns a list of orders. Can anyone give an idea how we could group the list, but retain the List as a data type, since that's what the GetOrders method in OrderService does?

What I tried:

We all thought about using the GroupBy method [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-8.0), but I don't think that it returns a list at all.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Once you group the orders, it’s no longer a list of orders - it’s effectively a list of groups, each of which contains the orders in that group..

Comment: As long as each order contains the field you want to group on (e.g. status), you can just group by that field in the frontend. It doesn't seem necessary to put the grouping into the backend.

Answer (score 0):

If your output must be a list (or sequence) of objects rather than a list of grouped items (a list of lists) then the closest you can get is to order the list by the grouping criteria. What matters to the end user is how you display that list in the application... and you can perform whatever grouping and/or ordering you desire in the application layer.

`GroupBy` is a difficult beast because it produces different results on SQL than in-memory. The actual ordering depends heavily on the SQL generated by the ORM you're using, and I've yet to find an ORM that produces the same order from an SQL query as I get from the equivalent statement in-memory. As such you should probably avoid trying to use `GroupBy` for ordering and use the `SortBy` extension(s) whenever sorting is desired.

Grouping for display is common practice, and it's an entirely application-layer concern. If your application guarantees a particular order in the source data for the ASP.NET page you can potentially generate group headers by tracking the group key on each record and inserting a header row when the key changes, which preserves the order of the data as supplied by the data layer. This can be desirable in paged lists where the controller handles row selection based on a well-defined ordering.

For example, let's use a simplified view model:

```
public record OrderViewModel
(
    Guid OrderID, 
    Guid VendorID,
    string VendorName,
    string ItemName,
    Decimal ItemCost,
    int Quantity,
    Decimal Total
);
```

Let's assume that the data we're going to render is already sorted by `VendorName` and some other (very important but not delivered in the view model) fields. You can render this into an HTML table with grouping in a variety of ways including:

```html
@(
   var lastVendorID = Guid.Empty;
)
<table>
@foreach (var order in Model)
{
    if (order.VendorID != lastVendorID)
    {
        lastVendorID = order.VendorID;
        <tr class="vendor-row"><td colspan=4>@order.VendorName</td></tr>
    }
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td>@order.ItemName</td>
        <td>@($"${order.ItemCost:#,0.00}")</td>
        <td>@order.Quantity</td>
        <td>@($"${order.Total:#,0.00}")</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

If we don't assume that the source is already ordered then you can apply ordering in the `foreach`:

```
@foreach (var order in Model.OrderBy(o => o.VendorName))
```

The moral of the story is: don't `GroupBy` where a simple `OrderBy` is all you need.

---

More generally, `GroupBy` should probably be restricted to two main use-cases:

1. Partitioned aggregation (summarizing groups of records).
2. Adding group-level information to the data.

Either case involves a distinctly different output record from your plain list of `Order` items. Either you're producing a list of summary data or adding information related to the group as a whole. For instance:

```
public record OrderGroupViewModel
(
    // Group key and display data
    Guid GroupID,
    string GroupName,
    // summarized from order data:
    int OrderCount,
    Decimal TotalOrderValue,
    // Line item collection - could be List<> or whatever you prefer
    Order[] Orders
)
```

Your table generation code then nests two loops: an outer loop for the `OrderGroupViewModel` and an inner for the `Orders` collection. You can do the summaries, sort and select on the order list (display the top 10 value orders for instance) or whatever else you desire at display rather than building it into complex business logic.